# Warning about Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: ios, warnings, xcode7

```
static id SLRandomValueFromArray(NSArray *array) {
    if ([array count] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)arc4random_uniform([array count])]; // WARNING HERE
}
```

The warning says

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'u_int32_t' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

I've never come across this warning before and not really sure how to resolve this with Xcode 7 and iOS 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
[array objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)[array count])]
```

Reason:

This is the `arc4random_uniform` in stdlib.h,its input is `u_int32_t`

```
u_int32_t arc4random_uniform(u_int32_t /*upper_bound*/)
```

But the `[array count]` return NSUInteger,so you need to cast